# How to display custom names in image galleries (toast message)

Tags: android, image, gallery, toast

I am looking for a way to show a toast messages in your average android gallery. BUT...I want to set custom names for each image that displays when the image is selected. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a listener to your gallery

```
setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
```

when a item is selected this method

```
@Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
```

which is a method from the OnItemSelectedListener class is going to get called, the position relates to the selected item in your gallery that you could use to display any information about that item using a Toast message. Hope this helps.